# ui-grid edit mode with textarea

Tags: angularjs, textarea, angular-ui-grid, editmode

I have a ui-grid and one of the fields is editable. I have set the editableCellTemplate to be an html that has a TEXTAREA.  There are 2 issues. Issue 1 is that I have set the textarea to show 4 rows but it shows only 1. Setting the height of the editable doesn't seem to have any affect. I can set the height of the row and then it shows up, but then I end up with every row in non-edit mode to be that height and it takes up way too much room.
Issue 2, hitting ENTER in the textarea exits edit mode rather than just moving to the next line in the textarea. I see in the docs that ENTER is one of the "End Edit" keys. How do I override this to turn off the END EDIT for ENTER in this cell?

Comment: So it seems that this behavior is controlled by a DIV tag. So removing the DIV tag from my cellEditTemplate and just having a FORM with a TEXTAREA inside resolved the issue of hitting ENTER